# Определить средство выразительности

Tags: стилистика

> На Камчатке я с интересом наблюдал за
> молодой медведицей. Увидев блестящую
> спинку лосося, ловкая охотница делала
> стремительный выпад, и рыба была в ее
> пасти.

Помогите найти два средства выразительности.

Comment: Серж,белоснежный цветок, белобрысый парень-оценочная лексика, где "белоснежный" означает восхищение, а "белобрысый" пренебрежение, причём белоснежный - это ещё и эпитет, образное сравнение цветка с белым снегом, а вот "белобрысый" -просто сниженное прилагательное в прямом значении, образности там нет. Оценочные -любые слова, где мы даём оценку -плохо или хорошо относимся, это и сущ., и прилаг., и наречия, а эпитет - это прилагат.(редко наречие)обычно в переносном смысле, образное или очень красивое

Comment: Серж,насчёт"Вряд ли выпад назовешь действием" выпад в фехтовании и тяжёлой атлетике -это бросок, как раз резкое действие. Но нам-то важно её сравнение со спортсменкой, а не резкое действие( его и животные делают, это просто фразеологизм, не средство образности). Я об этом с самого начала говорю, а меня не понимают.

Comment: Людмила, я вам ответил в комментарии. См.ниже.

Comment: Людмила, скорее движение, а не действие. Но это уже не важно. Т.к. уже приведен полный контекст, что меняет суть дела.

Comment: Людмила, ''Серебряные коньки, шелковые кудри'' - это эпитеты. Где здесь переносное значение? Или: **Цветок засохший, безуханный**,
Забытый в книге вижу я ( Пушкин). 

> Эпитет  - слово, определяющее, поясняющее, характеризующее какое-нибудь свойство или качество понятия, явления, предмета.Используя эпитет, писатель выделяет те свойства и признаки изображаемого им явления, на которые он хочет обратить внимание читателя.  Переносное значение необязательно.

Comment: Так что ''белобрысый'' самый настоящий эпитет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Олицетворение (медведица делала выпад, как спортсменка) и перифраз: ловкая охотница = медведица. А почему два? Есть эпитеты ловкая, стремительный - хоть и не в переносном смысле, но образные прилагательные.

**Добавочка**:
Если Вы не хотите назвать "сделала выпад" олицетворением,назовите метафорой(олицетворение тоже метафора), здесь скрытое сравнение со спортсменкой-фехтовальщицей. будет 2 средства - эпитеты и метафора, но есть и фразеологизм "сделать выпад"-https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D , правда, он здесь не как худ.средство, а как грамматическая единица :сделала выпад = ринулась, бросилась, а как худ. средство употребляется в значении"враждебно высказалась".

Comment: А с удивлением - это оценочная лексика?
Олицетворение - это наделение неодушевленных предметов живыми качествами, можно ли применить олицетворение к живым существам ( медведице)?
Задание было именно найти два средства выразительности, перифраз пока еще не проходили

Comment: Нет, это не оценочная лексика. Про оценочную лексику можете подробно прочитать здесь:[Эмоционально-экспрессивная окраска слов](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook028/01/part-008.htm#i1857)

Comment: Есть широкое и узкое понимание олицетворения   http://rithelp.ru/2010/11/olicetvorenie/          
Олицетворение — это  особая семантическая разновидность такого понятия, как метафора, а именно троп, выразительность которого связана с тем, что неодушевлённые предметы, явления природы, животные наделяются человеческими свойствами: чувствами, действиями, поступками, речью. http://formaslov.ru/%D0%BE   ,http://literatura5.narod.ru/olicetvorenie.html

Comment: pingvin,Вам нужно разобрать только два предложения или весь текст? А то "скоротечного лета" - явный эпитет.

Comment: А в каком Вы классе, что перифраз не проходили? В 9-м уже должны проходить

Comment: Людмила, в том-то и дело, что здесь нет никаких человеческих качеств, которые можно перенести на животных.

Comment: Серж,я говорю о том, что медведица-охотница сделала выпад. Во-первых, выпад - это упражнение для лыжников, конькобежцев и фехтовальщиков для укрепления мышц ног.
 ( https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B )Кстати,делать выпад -фразеологизм, тоже худ. выразит.средство, кот. в 7 классе проходили.
  
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D

Comment: Людмила, белоснежный цветок, белобрысый парень, что это - эпитеты или оценочная лексика?

Comment: Вряд ли выпад назовешь действием. Под действием скорее имеются в виду поступки.А вот скрытое сравнение действительно на лицо. Автор сравнивает движение медведицы со сложным спортивным упражнением.Прочитал весь контекст. В полном контексте, который приводит pingvin, медведица - ловкая рыбачка - делала выпад. Конечно, медведица здесь олицетворяется.

Answer (score 1):

Людмила, а где вы видите олицетворение? Здесь ведь ничего не приписывается к медведице. В примере два средства выразительности: перифраз и эпитеты.

Comment: А кому же это приписывается? Первое предложение прочитайте. Вот весь текст:Видеть дикое животное в естественных условиях доводится не каждому.На Камчатке я с интересом и удивлением наблюдал за молодой медведицей.Рано утром выспавшись в берлоге она спускалась к реке и неторопливо входя в воду высматривала добычу.Увидев блестящую спинку лосося ловкая охотница делала стремительный выпад и рыба была в её пасти.Наевшись рыбачка ложилась на камни нагретые солнцем и наслаждалась теплом скоротечного лета.

Comment: Здесь без знаков препинания, ученики сами должны поставить

Comment: Людмила привела полностью текст. Эпитеты я нашла. Перифраз не проходили (7 класс)

Comment: Проходили - метафора, олицетворение, слова с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами, оценочная лексика, эпитеты.

Comment: Людмила, назовите мне предложение, где медведице переписывается какое-нибудь человеческое качество. То что медведица делала выпад - это еще не олицетворение. Тогда в тексте, где описывается  действие животного,  выразительном средством нужно считать олицетворение.

Comment: Ловкая охотница, блестящую спинку, стремительный выпад, скоротечного лета, - оценочная лексика.

Comment: Людмила, если они не проходили перифраз, то вполне может быть под ''ловкой охотницей'' - имеется в виду олицетворение, т.е. автор приписывает качества охотницы медведице.

Comment: Серж, А чем оценочная лексика отличается от эпитета? В ваших примерах это разве не эпитеты?

Comment: Олицетворение мы проходили только наделение неодушевленным предметам свойст живых существ(

Comment: Оценочная лексика,т.е. слова экспрессивно-окрашенные,напр.: великолепный, белобрысый, могут быть эпитетами.

Comment: Здесь оценочная лексика только "спинка" - сущ. с ласково-уменьшительным суффиксом -инк-, вряд ли это имелось в виду, любуется он медведицей, а не лососем.
А все образные прилагательные - эпитеты (Ловкая, стремительный, скоротечного). А вот "наслаждалась" я бы тоже назвала олицетворением. pingvin, по-моему, на этот счёт не следует заморачиваться, что они имели в виду, вам же не нужно найти ВСЕ средства, нужно привести пример двух - этого достаточно, чтобы охарактеризовать текст как художественно выразительный и изобразительный, ведь медведица ведёт себя как человек - ловкая рыбачка.

Comment: А "блестящая" не пишите, это не эпитет, это в прямом значении - она же блестит.

Comment: Олицетворение - это наделение НЕЖИВОГО предмета качествами живого существа. Львица-то живое существо. Или сейчас по ФГОСам по-другому?